# Maximum sum of path from left column to right column

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to calculate the maximum sum that can be achieved in going from left column to right column in a grid. Allowed movements are up, down, right. I've implemented this solution (it's Breadth First Search) :

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    Queue<Position> q = new LinkedList<Position>();
    q.add(new Position(i, 1));
    dp[i][1] = map[i][1];

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        Position node = q.poll();
        visited[node.n][node.m] = 1;
        if(dp[node.n][node.m] > max) {
            max = dp[node.n][node.m];
        }
        if(visited[node.n-1][node.m] != 1 && node.n != 1 && dp[node.n-1][node.m] < dp[node.n][node.m] + map[node.n-1][node.m] && map[node.n-1][node.m] != -1) {
            dp[node.n-1][node.m] = dp[node.n][node.m] + map[node.n-1][node.m];  

            q.add(new Position(node.n-1, node.m));
        }
        if(visited[node.n+1][node.m] != 1 && node.n != n && dp[node.n +1][node.m] < dp[node.n][node.m] + map[node.n+1][node.m] && map[node.n+1][node.m] != -1) {
            dp[node.n +1][node.m] = dp[node.n][node.m] + map[node.n+1][node.m];
            q.add(new Position(node.n + 1, node.m));
        }
        if(visited[node.n][node.m+1] != 1 && node.m != m && dp[node.n][node.m+1] < dp[node.n][node.m] + map[node.n][node.m+1] && map[node.n][node.m+1] != -1) {
            dp[node.n][node.m+1] = dp[node.n][node.m] + map[node.n][node.m+1];
            q.add(new Position(node.n, node.m+1));
        }

    }
}
static class Position {
        int n, m;
        public Position(int row, int column) {
            this.n = row;
            this.m = column;
        }
    }
```

Example Input:

```
-1 4 5 1
2 -1 2 4
3 3 -1 3
4 2 1 2
```

The problem with my solution is it should reach 2 (in last row 2nd column) by following 4->3->3->2 but my solution put 2 in visited state so it won't check it. And if I remove visited array, it will get trapped in infinite loop of up, down, up, down on any cell.

**Edit :** Each point can be visited only once.

Comment: `4->3->3->2` does not reach the last column. Can you clarify the problem statement please?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32679720/572670 Seems like you have different set of moves though.

Comment: 2 at postion (4,2), can be reached by 4->2 as well as 4->3->3->2, but I want one with maximum points so it should reach there by second option. The problem is after reaching 4->2 it sets 2 as already visited so 4->3->3 won't consider 2 for next position

Comment: Also, if you allow up,down,right - you can use a loop as much times as you want (if it's up-down loop), and get "better" score. If you are looking for only *simple paths* (without loops), this is longest path problem, which is NP-Hard.

Comment: Just to clarify your allowed moves; by "up" and "down" you actually mean "right-up" and "right-down", correct? Otherwise as amit pointed out you can have infinitely long solutions.

Comment: @amit Problem is the different sets of move, already checked that link

Comment: @Sh3ljohn no, by up and down I actually mean up and down, and that's my problem it can get stuck in infinite checking

Comment: @crysis - I know it's been a long time since you asked this question but if possible, could you please add the link to this question as i want to test my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved with a linear programming approach, but there is a small twist because you cannot visit each cell more than once but the movements can actually take you to that condition.

To solve the issue you can however note that in a given position `(x, y)` you either

- just arrived at `(x, y)` from `(x-1, y)` and therefore you are allowed to go up, down or right (unless you're on the edges, of course)
- arrived at `(x, y)` from `(x, y-1)` (i.e. from above) and then you're allowed only to go down or right
- arrived at `(x, y)` from `(x, y+1)` (i.e. from below) and then you're allowed only to go up or right

This translates directly in the following recursive-memoized solution (code is in Python):

```
matrix = [[-1, 4, 5, 1],
          [ 2,-1, 2, 4],
          [ 3, 3,-1, 3],
          [ 4, 2, 1, 2]]
rows = len(matrix)
cols = len(matrix[0])
cache = {}

def maxsum(dir, x, y):
    key = (dir, x, y)
    if key in cache: return cache[key]
    base = matrix[y][x]
    if x < cols-1:
        best = base + maxsum("left", x+1, y)
    else:
        best = base
    if dir != "above" and y > 0:
        best = max(best, base + maxsum("below", x, y-1))
    if dir != "below" and y < rows-1:
        best = max(best, base + maxsum("above", x, y+1))
    cache[key] = best
    return best

print(max(maxsum("left", 0, y) for y in range(rows)))
```

If you are not allowed to step over a negative value (even if that would guarantee a bigger sum) the changes are trivial (and you need to specify what to return if there are no paths going from left column to right column).

Comment: I tried to add  these 2 conditions : "if dir != "above" and y == 0:
        best = max(best, maxsum("below",x,rows-1))
if dir != "below" and y == rows-1:
        best = max(best,maxsum("above",x,0))" to implement teleportation from bottom row to top (it loses all points earned to teleport) and top row to bottom row. But it's giving wrong answer. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @crysis: the problem is that with wrap-around moves you can get into a loop (for example just moving down with wrap around) thus passing multiple times from the same cell. An easy way to handle wrapping is replacing `dir` with the number of steps done (e.g. -2 meaning that i got to x/y moving down twice, 0 meaning "left"). Note that this will take complexity from O(rows×cols) to O(rows²×cols) because the space state increases.

Comment: what will be the base case for avoiding negative cells (-1 values) ? I am not getting correct answer